# Why there is a sudden change from positive to negative after changing $dt$ to $d\sigma$?

Tags: integration, differential, lyapunov-functions, delay-differential-equations

[image]

I wonder why there is a negative sign after changing $dt$ to $d\sigma$ on the third line.

Comment: If we consider expression inside $g$ as $y$, then $dg/dt = g’y’dt/d\sigma$. $dg/d\sigma= -g’y’d\sigma/dt$

Comment: @sku i'm sorry because i can't see it... why $\frac{d\sigma}{dt}$ appear at the final term? the prime $'$ representing the $t-$ or $\sigma-$derivative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making sku's comment more explicit, consider $g$ as the function composition $(g \circ y)(c)$, where $y$ is everything inside of $g$ and $c = t-\sigma$.
By the chain rule,
$$
{\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}t} = {\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}y} {\mathrm{d}y \over \mathrm{d}c} {\partial c \over \partial t} = {\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}y} {\mathrm{d}y \over \mathrm{d}c}
$$
and
$$
{\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}\sigma} = {\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}y} {\mathrm{d}y \over \mathrm{d}c} {\partial c \over \partial \sigma} = -{\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}y} {\mathrm{d}y \over \mathrm{d}c}
$$
therefore,
$$
{\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}t} = -{\mathrm{d}g \over \mathrm{d}\sigma}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.